# How can I use jQuery with Ionic 2?

Tags: jquery, typescript, ionic2

I have been given some JQuery code that I need to use with my ionic 2 project. How can I include it and the JQuery library?

The code looks like this (this is just a part of it):

```js
// on 'Left Down' button click:
jQuery('body').on('click', '.left-down', function (e) {
  
 jQuery('body #top-scale').stop();
 jQuery('body .right-hand-weight').stop();
 jQuery('body .left-hand-weight').stop();
 //top of scale animation
 jQuery("body #top-scale").animate({
    transform: "rotate("+ setWeights(3,0) +"deg)"
 })
 

  //===rotate + reposition each weight *** 
  jQuery("body .right-hand-weight").animate({
    transform:"rotate("+ getWeights() +"deg) translateX("+getX("right")+"px,"+getY("right")+"px)"
   })

  jQuery("body .left-hand-weight").animate({
    transform:"rotate("+ getWeights() +"deg) translateX("+getX("left")+"px,"+getY("left")+"px)"
   })

  //console.log(getWeights());

  // set number value in weight 
  jQuery( "body .text-1" ).text( leftWeightPercentage );

});
```

I was thinking of putting a script src tag in the index.htm for the JQuery library and the jquery code file I have been given, but I can't work out how to import the code into my ionic 2 project.

Comment: I was thinking of putting a script src tag in the index.htm for the JQuery library and the jquery code file I have been given, but I can't work out how to import the code into my ionic 2 project.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Updated at:** 12/04/2018

**1.** First of all, install jQuery in your ionic project:

`$ npm install jquery --save`

**2.** After that, install jQuery global derectory to typings (so you can import it):

```
$ npm install @types/jquery
```

**3.** Then, you can import JQuery in the page/component where you want to use it (*for example: home.ts*), with the following code:

`import * as $ from 'jquery'`

And that's all, now it should be working.

---

**Checking:**

To check if it worked , you can simply try the following:

**1.** In your component/page (*for example: home.html*) add an element with an specific id (*in this case: myButton*), and a method:

`<button id="myButton" (click)="changeTextColor()">Click Me!</button>`

**2.** In your component/page: (*in this case: home.ts*) add the method:

`changeColor(){
  $('#myButton').text('white');
}`

And that should change the text of the button.

Comment: Before using typings command in step 2, you may need to install typings first by running this command:

npm install -g typings

Comment: Instead of step 2 or installing typings, run npm install @types/jquery

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @WilboBaggins, i have already updated the answer.

Comment: Warning! This broke my ionic app. It froze during the build after doing this and I had to uninstall. I am an ionic newb, so if you know what you're doing, it's probably fine. But newbs beware.

Comment: i did the same , on mac, the visual studio said cannot find module jquery.
and working fine on android , but not working on ios