# How to include jQuery in ionic 2 Angular app

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am creating an ionic 2 app. I am a new angular 2 developer, so sorry if I miss some things. I want to include jQuery and other js files to page components.

I used this method:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import '../../assets/js/jquery-2.1.1.js';
import '../../assets/js/prog-bar.js';
import '../../assets/js/myApp.js';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

okay it loaded the files but it gives me error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

So I tried to include jquery lib :

```
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

but I don`t know what to do next.
how to use Jquery lib in my app in a good way,
please don't tell me to add the script tag to the index.html page because it is being removed every time I rerun the app.

Comment: [This question is already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305422/using-jquery-with-ionic-2)

Answer (score 2):

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

The above should work if you have done this:

```
System.config({
defaultJSExtensions: true,
paths: {
    // paths serve as alias
    'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
map: {
    'app':  'app',
    jquery: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js',
    material: 'npm:material-design-lite/dist/material.min.js',

    // angular bundles
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    ....
},
packages: {
    app: { main: 'main', format: 'register', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
},
});
```

Also don't forget you should have a typings.json that points to your jquery typing file.

Just a note, if you don't find the `system.config.js` file then look for a webpack file to change. If you find one, `webpack.config.js` just add this to it:

`plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      jquery: 'jquery'
    })
  ]`

Comment: don't you have a `systemjs.config.js ` file? If you don't see it, then I think Ionic might have moved to webpack

Comment: no i don`t i just created an app as the ionic 2 docs said , i didn't include any files .

Comment: so sorry for being idiot :( . but i find more than webpack file . so please can u provide full path or at least the file extension

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in following ways.

1. Optimum - Importing it in your component file.

   - Install jQuery and its typings - 

     `npm install jquery --save 
     npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`
   - Import it in top of your `*.component.ts` using **any of followings** -

     - `import * as $ from 'jquery';`.
     - OR - `import 'jquery';` and declare both of these (as global variables) -

       - `declare let $:any;`
       - `declare let jQuery:any;`
2. Not optimum - You can also include `jQuery CDN link` in the `head` of `index.html` present under `src/` folder of your root project.

Also, in Ionic, the `webpack.config.js` file is present under `node_modules` folder which will get replaced after doing `npm install`.

Comment: But how do I go about this @SujitKumarSingh, I still get `Runtime Error
jQuery is not defined`. I as well don't get what you meant by `declare let $:any` `declare let jQuery:any`. Under what black do I define then in ts file?

Comment: By the 1st method `import * as $ from 'jquery'`, I am importing `everything` from jQuery libraru as `$`. But that may not be always useful because there are few libraries using `jQuery` instead of `$`. Thus I mentioned 2nd option too which imports `jQuery` and then declares variables used in it. `import 'jquery'`, `declare let $:any;` and `declare let jQuery:any` will be one after another in 3 lines of code (in sequence). By doing this you are basically defining 2 new variables `$` and `jQuery` of `any` data type.

Comment: If you are adding/importing external `jQuery` plugin then `point 1` will not work. It will give `Error: jQuery is not defined` pointing to the imported `jQuery plugin file`. For that I have asked similar quetion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45811325/importing-jquery-plugin-jquery-shorten-in-typescript-angular-4/45818283) and in [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/importing-old-jquery-plugin-in-ionic/103713). For that situation I have mentioned to include `jQuery CDN link` under header of `index.html` in `point 2`, which is main template for angular app.