# How to disable vertical scrolling while sliding ion slide in iOS?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

In ionic 3 ,Using iPhone when sliding ionic slider the vertical scrolling occur, it causes app ui experience. it’s serious bug I have tried many ideas in googling no one works. please help me any one aware of this issue

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem with some sliders on our project. The first slide was ok, you could slide left & right without any vertical scroll, however any further slides would scroll the whole page up & down. What fixed it for us was to add the following css:

```
.swiper-wrapper{
    width:auto !important;
}
```

The .swiper-wrapper was width: 100%, and then being pushed to the left (and off screen) when scrolled. So any further swipes on the slider were outwith the swiper-wrapper thus causing the whole page to move.

Answer (score 1):

i have the solution! 
ionSlideDrag Emitted when a slide moves. When the slide moves i call a function which add a class to my content which add

```
overflow-y: hidden.
```

ionSlideDidChange Emitted when a slide change ends. it means that when slide change ends i call a function which remove the class and my content is again scrollable.

For add and remove class i have implemented jquery. ( [How can I use jQuery with Ionic 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305422/how-can-i-use-jquery-with-ionic-2))

this is an example of my code:

in my view.html

```
<ion-slides slidesPerView="4" spaceBetween="20" (ionSlideDrag)="dragging()" (ionSlideDidChange)="endDragging()">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let action of actionPages">
    <img [src]="url + action.imgSmall">
    <h1></h1>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

in my view.ts

```
dragging(){
 $("#contenitore").addClass("no-scroll")
}

endDragging(){
  $("#contenitore").removeClass("no-scroll")
}
```

no-scroll class in app.scss:

```
 .no-scroll {
    div.scroll-content {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
}
```